# select from two different table and display

Tags: php, mysql

i have 2 different table named productlist and rsales

the ff data in productlist are

```
id|pcode|
1 |1220 |

and the ff data in rsales are

id|total|total_discount|
3 |500  |      50      |
```

my problem is that i want to select data from two different table which is productlist and rsales and display it horizontally. i tried everything but it display vertically. the result must be something like this

```
id|pcode|total|total_discount|
1 |1220 |500  |   50         |
```

this is my code so far but it only display data from single table

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("inventory", $con);



$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM productlist");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$row['pcode'].'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Use join for two tables. So that you can get values in single row.

Comment: Where is the link between `productlist` and `rsales`? Also, using `mysql_*` is now strongly discouraged. The library is deprecated and you should really be using MySQLi or PDO...

Comment: You propably want to read this:
[MySql Join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: There is no relevant column between these tables. Based on which column you want to merge data between these tables.

Comment: im just new to php and don't really know all. how can i apply what you are trying to say sir :)

Comment: there is no link between rsales and produclist i just wanna get data from these table.

Comment: hi there, @Mani is telling you that you need a common bit of info in each row to be able to link the data from different tables together. I linked a Q&A that I posted a while back in my answer below. You would do really well to have a good read of it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there is no link between rsales and produclist but you can try like this, you will get all fileds from both the tables using this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM productlist,rsales");
```

Comment: this is awesome code simple and direct. but what about if im going to sum the "total" value from rsale? any idea sir? i tried sum(total) but error appears :D

Comment: for that you need to define all the column names instead of (*) in your query with sum(total)

Answer (score 0):

Is the id difference between them offset by 2?If so,you can use **Fluffeh** answer like this:

```
select
 ffdata.pcode,
 rsales.total,
 rsales.total_discount
from
 ffdata
    join rsales
        on ffdata.id=rsales.id+2
```

Comment: This won't work as the tables have a different number of columns - nor would it really work anyhow as the data would come out on different rows - which is not what the question asked for.

Comment: i think union can't be use for the  kind of problem because there is no link or no common at all i just want to get data from two table . but i tried this code and error appears Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\eduards.org\admin\itemsales.php on line 136

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a join in your SQL so that the data comes out in a single row in the results and is matched on the correct fields.

I wrote a [lengthy Q&A about it a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables) for just this sort of question which you will really do well to read, but in short, your query should look something like this:

```
select
    ffdata.pcode,
    rsales.total,
    rsales.total_discount
from
    ffdata
        join rsales
            on ffdata.id=rsales.id
```

This is assuming that you have a common key on the two tables that links the records.